# Geocoding error MMQGIS plug-in on QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, google-maps, mmqgis

Using the mmqgis plug-in for QGIS 3, I tried to geocode some addresses, but get the following error: "Failure connecting to maps.googleapis.com:

I am doing the following: MMQGIS tab -> Geocode CSV with Google/OpenStreetMap -> enter csv file, which has address, city, and state

I've tried with and without an Api key. I've also tried with OpenStreetMap. No results.